# android using Renderscript for blur effect crashes causes A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x9e6fa000 in tid 482 (AsyncTask #1)

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, renderscript

I use blur effect,while applying to bitmap loaded from resources it works as expected,while using universal-imageloader to download image and applying to bitmap it causes 
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x9d56e000 in tid 31955 (AsyncTask #1)

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ImageView ivBackground;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    ivBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_background);
    String imageUri = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/Macau-bus-1032.jpg";
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            .showImageOnFail(Color.TRANSPARENT)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .cacheInMemory(false)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
            .build();

    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, ivBackground, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {


        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(final String imageUri, View view, final Bitmap loadedImage) {
Bitmap bmpTest = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
//final Bitmap cropedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpTest, 0, 0, bmpTest.getWidth() / 2, bmpTest.getHeight());
final Bitmap cropedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0, loadedImage.getWidth() / 2, loadedImage.getHeight());

            ivBackground.setImageBitmap(cropedBitmap);
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ivBackground.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            return blurBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap aVoid) {
                    ivBackground.setImageBitmap(aVoid);
                }
            }.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }
    });
}
private Bitmap blurBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(MyActivity.this);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation allIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);
    Allocation allOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outBitmap);
    blurScript.setRadius(25.f);
    blurScript.setInput(allIn);
    blurScript.forEach(allOut);
    allOut.copyTo(outBitmap);
    bitmap.recycle();
    rs.destroy();
    return outBitmap;
}
```

}